# Sorcery notifications if activation status is pending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, sorcery

How to make sorcery gem show specific error when trying to log in account with 'pending' activation status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while trying to figure it out until I hadnt found a way to do that in a github repository issues [here](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/issues/232) written by [him](https://github.com/kentaroi)
So I just wanted to copy (and change a bit) it here so it would be easier to find it if somebody else had this problem.

1) in config/initializers/sorcery.rb change to

```
user.prevent_non_active_users_to_login = false
```

2) Change or rewrite somewhere 'login' method as shown here:

```
     def login(*credentials)
        @current_user = nil
        if credentials[0].is_a?(user_class)
          user = credentials.shift
          credentials.unshift(nil, nil)
        else
          user = user_class.authenticate(*credentials)
        end
        if user
          old_session = session.dup.to_hash
          reset_sorcery_session
          old_session.each_pair do |k,v|
            session[k.to_sym] = v
          end
          form_authenticity_token

          auto_login(user)
          after_login!(user, credentials)
          current_user
        else
          after_failed_login!(credentials)
          nil
        end
      end
```

3) And in controller you can use something as the following:

```
  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    if user
      if user.activation_state == 'active'
        login(user, params[:remember_me])
        redirect_back_or_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in"
      else
        render :pending
      end
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password was invalid"
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is in `config/initializers/sorcery.rb` set 
`prevent_non_active_users_to_login = false`

Then in your sessions controller, or whenever you call `login()`, users who haven't activated yet will still be authenticated and you can do a further check against `@user.activation_state == 'active'` to decide what to do (show a different message and redirect, etc)